# Language fallback for unpublished translation

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

on our Drupal 7, we have pages in 6 different languages. We'd like to remove the translation for some nodes.

I thought that users would be automatically redirected to the default (English) language when trying to access this unpublished translation, but this is not the case, they have a "not found" page.

I installed the language fallback module and configured all languages to fallback to English, but this did not help.

Is there something else I can do so that all traffic to unpublished translations is redirected to the default node translation ?

Answer (score 0):

I never used it, but this module seems correspond to your problem https://www.drupal.org/project/multilink

Comment: Excellent, thanks ! I enabled Multilink, Multilink Redirect and Multilink Redirect Cached.

Comment: Sorry, I answered to quickly or I did something wrong when testing, but this actually doesn't work. If I unpublish a translation and I try to access it via it's alias (or direct node/id link, it's the same), I get a permission denied error.